# Movie about putting stones together or taking them apart to turn a father into a monster

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I saw this movie along time ago when I was a kid. It’s a scary movie about a stone you can put the stones together and the father will turn into a monster or you could break the stone and the dad would turned into a monster, I can’t remember.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you see this?  We don't know when you were a kid.  Was it a live-action movie or animated?